# How to work on Treeview control to support drag & drop in Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

> Can anybody recommend a treeview component for WINDOWS APP that supports drag & drop (between it's own nodes - it's for a content management system to rearrage the pages). Don't mind if it's open source or commercial (can't quite stretch to the treeview from Telerik though). Shame..

Any other options? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for something like [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4582-Drag-Drop-functionallity-tree-view.aspx)

> 1.Start a new Winforms project. Drag a treeview control on the form.
>
> 2.Fill the treeview with differents nodes via the TreeView Node collection property.
>
> 3.Go to property window set the **AllowDrop** property to **true**.
>
> 4.Finally write the code for three different events of tree view.The three event will will be ItemDrag,DragEnter and DragDrop.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

        private void OnItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
        {
            DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

        private void OnDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode NewNode;

            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode", false))
            {
                Point pt = ((TreeView)sender).PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                TreeNode DestinationNode = ((TreeView)sender).GetNodeAt(pt);
                NewNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode");

                if (DestinationNode.TreeView == NewNode.TreeView)
                {
                    DestinationNode.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)NewNode.Clone());
                    DestinationNode.Expand();
                    NewNode.Remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```